# Page refresh with AngularJs templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, url-routing

I am using ngRoute to serve up templates in my app.  So I will do something like this

```
$routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/templates/search.html', controller: 'SearchController' })
            .when('/SearchResults', { templateUrl: '/templates/searchResults.html', controller: 'SearchResultsController' })
            .when('/Problem', { templateUrl: '/templates/problem.html', controller: 'ProblemController' });
```

Say the user goes to /Problem and then hits the refresh button in the browser they are obviously going to get a 404 error because /Problem doesn't exist on the server.  Is there a standard way of handling this in angular?

Comment: Use a `.htaccess` to always redirect the user on the page where your webapp is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why you add a `#` before your hyperlink as shown in the angularjs tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

So for example: `<a href="#/Problem"></a>`

`#` will refer to the index site, and that's where angularjs will do your wished routing, even if the page is being refreshed, bookmarked, ...